# How to export custom jQuery functions in Require.js?

Tags: jquery, requirejs, amd

I defined a function and a jQuery function in an Require.js module(AMD) and I want to export them. Export the function is easy, but how to export the jQuery function? Thanks!

```
// filename: someModule.js
define(function (require, exports) {

    function funcA () {}

    $.fn.someFunc = function( callback ) {
        return this.someFunc1(xxx, callback );
    };
    $.fn.extend({
        someFunc2: function () {}
    });
    exports.funcA = funcA;
    // how to export $.fn.someFunc, so I can use it in another module?
    // and how to export someFunc2?

});
```

I am using this file in this way:

```
// another file: main.js
define(function (require, exports) {
    // this module is loaded by require.js
    var someModule = require('path/to/someModule');
    function init() {}
    exports.init = init;
});
```

and this file is rendered by a .ejs file by the server

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   require.config({
       baseUrl: '/asset',
       packages: [
        ...
       ]
   });
   require(['path/to/main.js'], function (main) {
       main.init();
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

What you have is a jQuery plugin. To make a jQuery plugin consumable by other code, setting `$.fn.someFunc` is *all* you need to do. The code that needs to use it will just have to list it as a dependency. Something like:

```
define(["jquery", "someFuncModule"], function ($) {
  $("some selector").someFunc(...);
});
```

There's no need to additionally export it from your AMD module.

Comment: Sorry. I've updated the question because I did omit some details of my project's structure. Can I require my someModule.js in main.js rather than changing the `ejs` file to require it? Thanks.